# Error when using scale_colour_gradientn() with geom_polygon()

Tags: r, ggplot2

When I try to use `scale_colour_gradientn()` with `geom_polygon()`, I get this error:

`Error in unit(tic_pos.c, "mm") : 'x' and 'units' must have length > 0`

This is a minimal example:

```
require(ggplot2)

data <- data.frame(group=c("1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2"), 
                   long=c(0, 2, 1, 2, 4, 3), 
                   lat=c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1), 
                   n=c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2))

ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data=data, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group, fill=n)) +
  scale_colour_gradientn(colours=rainbow(4))
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Change the scale to `scale_fill_gradientn(colours=rainbow(4))`. You haven't mapped a `color`
 variable.

Comment: Can't believe I missed that, thanks!

Comment: @Roland Would  it be worth to transform your comment into an answer? The error message is rather obsucre, so others might have the same problem and not realise where to look for the mistake. And in that case, the answer could be useful. Or should we flag it as being a simple typo?

Comment: @Stibu I believe this is a duplicate. I've seen confusion of `color` vs `fill` before, but I'm not in the mood to search for a duplicate to close with.